# How to merge branch back to master in GIT client Fork?

Tags: git

I am learning Git, and created a branch B5 from Master. Now I am trying out the GUI client Fork and simultaneously using TortoiseGit

All the previous branches I have played with B0, B1, B2 and B3, B4, etc. I had to:
1. Switch/Checkout to Master
2. Merge from B5

How do I  do this in the Fork GUI client?

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late for an answer but

[Fork git](https://git-fork.com/) client has all your local branches and remote(s) displayed on the left sidebar (similar to the image below), simply **double click** on the branch you want to switch to.

- If you want to create a new branch on a specific commit, just right-click the commit then choose to **Create a new branch**.
- If you want to fetch changes on an active repo but don't necessarily want to merge it yet, **right-click** on a remote and then click **Fetch origin** - origin being the name you've chosen for a repo.
- If you ever want to merge, you can simply **click and drag** the branch to whatever branch you want to merge it to, for instance, B2 to B1 then B1 to master etc...

[image: Fork Git Client]